# phpLiteAdmin v1.9.8.2 has "SQL?" showing up all over the page

Tags: sqlite

[Screenshot with SQL? everywhere.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSqPn.png)

I upgraded to the latest stable version; I tried changing themes; I've tried different hosting servers.  These SQL? messages still show up.  Sometimes there might only be 4 - 6 on the screen, sometimes, like the screenshot I added, there are so many, you have a hard time seeing your data.

I tried searching the phpliteadmin.org site, and the web using DuckDuckGo, but, as you can imagine, searching with the term "SQL?" gives you thousands of useless pages to sift through.

I can't be the only one who has this issue, so I'm sure someone has figured out what the problem is, right???

Thanks muchly!!

Answer (score 0):

Even if this question is 9 month old, i stumbled upon it while having the same issue - finally finding the solution to this:

The "SQL?"-outputs are just debug-information!

You can opt-out them in your phpliteadmin.config.php by changing
`$debug = true;`
into 
`$debug = false;`

Comment: Hey, Baldy, thanks for the reply.  You actually answered the question, but I didn't realize it.

I had tried this before, but it didn't work.  But the problem was on my end -- as a security measure, I had change the name(s) from phpliteadmin.xxx to plm.xxx.  What I did NOT do was change the code to match.  I renamed things back, and voila, it worked!  So I'm going to change the plm.php code to look for:
basename(__FILE__, '.php') . 'config.php'

So your answer made me go back and rethink why it wasn't working for me before.  Thanks!